# How to update the elements of an array in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, for-loop

I have an array called img. I want to check for the elements in the array which are negative, and then add 65536 to those elements. But for some reason, the array is not getting updated and when I print it, the old negative values are still being shown.

```
img = I
imgx,imgy = img.shape

for i in range(0,imgy):
    for j in range(0,imgx):
        if (img[i,j] < 0):
            img[i,j] = img[i,j] + 65536
            print(i,j,img[i,j])
```

I also tried this:

```
            img[i,j] = += 65536
```

instead of this:

```
            img[i,j] = img[i,j] + 65536
```

in the loop, but to no avail. When I print the indices and the elements after updating, in either case, this is what I'm getting:

```
i   j   img[i,j]
513 467 -31460
513 468 -31981
514 467 -30423
514 468 -31172
514 469 -32656
515 467 -31554
515 468 -31534
515 469 -32114
```

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here, but I'm kinda new to Python, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce your explained behaviour. Your code does change *img[i,j]*. I think your integer type is overflowing (adding 65536 creates a value to big to fit in the available number of bits, +65536 will overflow exactly to the old value with int16). You can shorten your code to `img[img < 0] += 65536` without the `for` loops.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thanks for the help!. As suggest by vivek599 in their comment, I just had to change the dtype. I also tried changing the dtype from int16 to int32 and the code then worked perfectly.

Comment: For your next question on stackoverflow: Please include your desired result and try to find a more descriptive title. It was not clear what you expect as an answer. Strictly speaking your accepted answer (which is a nice solution for your real question) does not find a solution for the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass any negative value to unsigned int , it will automatically roll over it to positive quantity. change your array type to unsigned int...

or

is it a thing in python such as unsigned int?????

Comment: Thanks Vivek! After changing the dtype of array from int16 to uint16, the negative values automatically rolled over to positive.